# WSO2 IS and API Manager SAML SSO - Login to store/publisher fail

Tags: api, wso2, single-sign-on, identity, saml

I configure IS and AM with SAML SSO as described in official [documentation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Single+Sign-on+with+SAML+2.0).
SSO login for AM console function well, I can log in as admin using unique credendital as defined in IS.
When I try to login to publisher or store, login is redirected to IS SamlSSO page as expected, but when I insert uid/pwd, browser is redirected to publisher login page asking for user credentials. AM carbon log report this WARN and ERROR:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-05-07 17:27:28,171]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  
Illegal access attempt at [2014-05-07 17:27:28,0171] from IP address 192.168.50.60 : 
Service is RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
{org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler}
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-05-07 17:27:28,172] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} - 
Access Denied. Please login first. {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Please login first.
at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:97)
```

any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Using the new AM 1.7.0 version the problem with publisher site remain the same, instead the store loop in IS SSO Login page without showing default page (with published API and login link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giovanni,

I made contact with WSO2 as I had the same problem and they directed me to https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2118

It appears that there maybe a bug in the priority of the SAMLSSOAuthentication and Basic Authentication. I followed the points in the above link and modified the APIMHOME/repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml and changed the priority for SAMLSSO from 10 to 0

I am now able to move between store/publisher and also carbon for API Manager, Identity Server also BAM.

Hope this helps

Carl.

Comment: I've always the same problem, when I insert uid/pwd on publisher SSO IS page, browser is redirected to publisher login page asking for user credentials. Store looping on SSO IS login page.

Comment: I restart all making a fresh install ...now it works with your suggestion, thanks!